# Can a library in Android have its own intent filters?

Tags: android

I'd like to develop a library that can be included in other Android applications to intercept certain kinds of intent. Is it possible?

I've created a library and a test project, both having their own `AndroidManifest.xml` files. In library's manifest I've defined an intent filter for action "TEST". But when I launch an intent with action "TEST" from the test project, that intent filter does not work.

Are intent filters from libraries ever used by Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are intent filters from libraries ever used by Android?

Presently, AFAIK, the manifest from the library is ignored. That might change in the future.

Comment: This is no longer the case if you use manifest merger, which is enabled by default in Gradle.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html