# Writing an Android library - Using its own custom Application class (getApplication)

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android library and I wish to use a custom `Application` class, which will be accessible from all of the library's activities (using the `getApplication` method).

The problem is when I call the `getApplication` method from one of my library's activities, it returns the application class of the app using my library (and not the custom class I declared in the library's Android manifest).

My current guess (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441424/1233767) and the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)) is that the application using my library must also declare the custom `Application` class in their Android manifest - which is a problematic solution, since that application can also have its own custom class (and a single app cannot have more than one custom `Application` class, right?).

Can anyone offer a better solution? (or verify that this solution is accurate)

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your custom Application implementation and AndroidManifest.xml. The correct way of using your custom Application in code is **casting**.

Suppose you have a MyApplication that extends android.app.Application, to get MyApplication instead of Application:

```
Boolean runInTest = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).isRunInTet();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that: What I meant was if my SDK uses a custom Application class, the main APK using my SDK also has to use that custom Application class (as declared in its Android manifest). And that is problematic, since the main APK can also have its own custom Application class.

Comment: @YaronBudowski, I don't see any problem of that, in your main APK, which custom Application class to use is configured via your main project's android manifest. Are you going to use both custom Application classes inside your main apk?

Comment: Since my code is a SDK, many APKs can use it, and some of them might have their own custom Application class - and as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), one APK cannot use two custom Application classes defined in its Android manifest file.

Comment: @YaronBudowski, yes, you are right. If you want use code from both custom Application classes, in your main project, try extends your Application class from the one you defined in Library Project, instead of android.os.Application, so you can maintain most reusable code in library project, without loss ability to minor customize it in main project.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's just one more annoying limitation of libraries in Android..